# Group Policy not applying on win8.1 machines

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, mappeddrive

I am trying to add a mapped drive for a specific set of users.

So far I have created the Policy object, linked it to the OU where the users are. Set the security filtering to the security group that contains the member users I am targeting.

When I test this by logging into a machine with one of those users I see the policy is correctly applying only on server machines or Win7/10 machines. The policy refuses to show up on a Win8.1 machine, including mine.

What I have done.
- I have logged off/rebooted multiple times
- I have run gpupdate & gpupdate /force
- I have run gpresult /r to confirm if the policy is there or not.
- Confirmed the policy is enabled in AD

I have not applied any security filter to a computer, just to a security group.

I'm looking for any additional advise or tools/commands I can use to try and investigate this.

Edit - Policy was applied 3 days ago. Also I've just narrowed this down such that is seems to affect only Windows 8.1 machines...

Edit 2 - Windows 7 or 10 machines are working as expected but Windows 8.1 are NOT. This test was done across 2 of each version...

Comment: i had same issue check this link
http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles-tutorials/windows-server-2008/Top-10-Reasons-Why-Group-Policy-Fails-to-Apply-Part1.html

Comment: can you post gpresult /h?